# How to apply EF migrations in other development environment?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I use source control for develop my project in two computer (team). I add migrations in first computer and update database, and I don't know how to apply migrations in other computer.
How to apply same migrations in other development environment?

Comment: Just run ```dotnet ef database update``` in your terminal on second pc

Comment: Is there one central development database or a database in each development environment? Can you not update the database the same as you do on the first computer?

Comment: Thank you #Neistow. It was so easy, I lost my mind.

Comment: It's not a central and I got my answer. Thank you all.